# Firestore document merge with Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to push a document to my Firebase Firestore database with *set()* and *{merge: true}*. I can't use *update()* because I can't guarantee that the doc exists beforehand.

If I was using Angular & TypeScript, the code would be:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
}

insertData() {
    this.firestore.collection('officePlants').doc('docXYZ')
        .set({
            'humidity': this.humiditySensorReading,
            'temperature': this.temperatureSensorReading
        },
            { merge: true });                                                   // provides an update and creates the doc if it doesn't exist
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Python:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import firebase_admin                                   # sudo pip install firebase-admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

credentials_path = 'myServiceAccount.privateKey.json'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = credentials_path

cred = credentials.Certificate(credentials_path)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection(u'officePlants').document('docXYZ')
doc_ref.set({
    u'humidity': humidity,
    u'temperature': temperature
}, {'merge': True})
```

But I'm getting the error:

> ValueError("Invalid merge path: {}".format(merge_path))
> ValueError: Invalid merge path: FieldPath('merge')

Removing the quotes, `{merge: True}` gives the error

> NameError: name 'merge' is not defined

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the syntax changes a bit in the Python version:

```
data = {
    u'humidity': humidity,
    u'temperature': temperature
}

doc_ref = db.collection(u'officePlants').document('docXYZ')
doc_ref.set(data, merge=True)
```